# Listen to AJAX load event of third party library

Tags: javascript, events, newsletter2go

I have a Newsletter2go subscription form on my site. I need to track the subscription with Google Analytics. Alas, Newsletter2Go only offers the display of a text, but no page redirect after the form was successfully submitted.

What I think should be done on my side is that I somehow need to catch the `load` event after the AJAX event was issued from the Newsletter2go script (which I cannot change).

My last resort would be to use `MutationObserver` to watch for Changes in the DOM (form disappears and Thank You text shows), but I suppose there should be a better way.

`document.addEventListener('load', /* ... */)` and `window.addEventListener('load', /* ... */)` didn't do anything

Comment: Newsletter2Go has an API. Part of that API are calls that can retrieve the structure of a form and can submit the data from that form. https://docs.newsletter2go.com/?version=latest#22cf6ae6-ae22-4cc6-8160-cded15a94fbb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this help topic 'How can I embed and customize the subscription form?'.

I only have the German version of the support text: https://newsletter2go-help-de.sendinblue.com/automation/formulare/wie-kann-ich-das-anmeldeformular-verwenden-einbetten-und-anpassen.html

In the chapter *Customize form* > *2 For coders* there is the solution described:
You can add callbacks to the call for `subscribe:createForm`. First is `successCallback`